# PGP signatures from Python?

Tags: python, security, cross-platform, gnupg

What is the easiest way to create and verify PGP/GPG signatures from within a Python application?

I can call pgp or gpg using subprocess and parse the output, but I was looking for a way that didn't require an external program to be installed (my application is cross-platform mac/windows/unix).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [GPGME](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/) and the [PyMe Python wrapper](http://pyme.sourceforge.net/) should do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to PyMe, consider [python-gnupg](http://code.google.com/p/python-gnupg/) and the [gnupginterface](http://py-gnupg.sourceforge.net/).